# Using ng-model on a dictionary value within an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

So I have an array that I've populated like so:

```
tempArray[tempProductName] = null;
tempArray[tempAttributeName] = response.data[0].Attributes[k].Name;
tempArray[tempAttributeValue] = null
$scope.newDayDisplay.push(tempArray);
```

I'm using this information in an ng-repeat like so:

```
                        </div>
                    <div class="row" ng-repeat="result in newDayDisplay">
                        <div class="col s2">

                            <md-input-container><label>{{result.AttributeName}}</label><input type="number" id="new-day-ARP-input" ng-model="result.AttributeValue" /></md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s4">
                            <label>Select Material</label>
                            <md-select ng-model="result.ProductName" md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader">
                                <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
                                    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" placeholder="Search For Material..." class="demo-header-searchbox md-text">
                                </md-select-header>
                                <md-option ng-value="{{mat.ID}}" ng-repeat="mat in Materials | filter:searchTerm">{{mat.Name}}</md-option>
                            </md-select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s2">
                            <p>{{result.AttributeValue}}</p>
                            <p>{{result.ProductName}}</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

The issue is that whenever I try to send this information as a post (the array) it does not bind the values for result.AttributeValue or result.ProductName to the respective value in the array "newDayDisplay".

So for example, I get
[image: Arrays]

But I want to be able to change those null values to the values entered on the modal.

I imagine this has to do with ng-repeat not working the way that I think that it does - does anyone know how to fix this?

Note that even if I do:

```
                            <div class="col s2">
                            <p>{{result.AttributeValue}}</p>
                            <p>{{result.ProductName}}</p>
                    </div>
```

I'm able to see the values I've selected, but the post doesn't take the values with it.

Here's an example of that binding:
[image: Binding in action]

Comment: What is the value when you post to server? Can you show that code here?

Comment: Currently, all it does it write the values that it receives: 
 public String SaveShipmentsAndReceipts(List<SnrAttribute> Test, DateTime time)
        {
            foreach(SnrAttribute snr in Test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(snr.Name.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(snr.ProductName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(snr.Value.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(time);

            }

Comment: But it says it has a nullreference error, so I'm thinking this might be where the problem lies?

Comment: So this is your back end api. How about the client side code?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't post all your logic here. I tried http://jsfiddle.net/q7hxqepv/ and it's working

Comment: I apologize for the delay - I figured it out!
You were right - it was the back-end logic.